# Validating Number using regex

Tags: regex

I need to validate if an input type is a number with some specifications using regex expressions. The number can have any number of commas(,) but not dots(.) but comma and dot should not be side by side such as

> 12,34,56,7.89 -- correct  --- 1
>
> 12.34.56 -- wrong  ---- 2
>
> 12345 -- correct ---- 3
>
> 123,45 -- correct ---- 4
>
> 123.45 -- correct --- 5
>
> 123,,45 -- wrong --- 6
>
> 12,345,678 -- correct --- 7

The expression I used is

> ((((\d+[.]?\d*)|(\d*[.]?\d+))[,]?)+\d+)

I am unable to solve test case 2 and 6. any help is acceptable thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qjFSAx/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a `,` followed by 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - matches a `.` followed by 1+ digits. `?` in the end makes this sub-pattern optional
- `$` - asserts the end of the line